# create-react-app: jQuery is not defined

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jquery-plugins, create-react-app

I am building a (pretty complex) React application (with `create-react-app` and TypeScript). I am also using React Router v4. Most of the time everything works alright.

Now I am using a number of external jQuery libraries which don't work well with webpack (such as jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js,jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js).

Because of that, I am loading my jQuery and all jQuery plugins in the `public/index.html` file, using the `<script>` tag, outside of webpack. (I know this is not the recommended way when working with `create-react-app` applications but I do it because of jQuery plugins not working with webpack).

Surprisingly every thing works fine, except in this specific case:
every time I enter in the browser search bar a url with at least two levels, the application crashes. For example, this works:

```
<Route path='/courses' component={<CourseListing />} />
```

and this does not:

```
<Route path='/courses/add-new' component={<CourseNew />} />
```

By 'working' I mean the corresponding `Route` component correctly renders its content.

When I enter this URL, the application reloads but this time jQuery (which is referenced in my application via `<script>` tag) does not reload. And every thing crash with this infamous error:

```
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

I know the crashing certainly has to do with me loading external jQuery library through script tag (and not the ES6 npm version in node_modules).

But it works mostly. What I would like to understand is why the crashing occures only when I enter a url (with 2 levels) through the browser url bar? Could the React Router v4 library have something to do with it?

I don't want to eject from the `create-react-app` managed environment.

Any input from the community toward the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Comment: are the script tags loading files relative to your own folders? like `<script src="/jquery-plugin">` ?

Comment: Yes. They are loading relative to the public folder

Comment: I have been able to narrow the problem to one particular library: the jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js plugin which has a dependency tweenlite.js. This dependency for some reason cannot be loaded true webpack...I am going to open a new question about it

Comment: try adding `<base href="/">` to you head tag

Comment: Sorry I could not understand. I dont know what is a <base /> tag. Do you mean <a href="/" /> ?

Comment: no I mean base, like this https://github.com/NCI-GDC/portal-graphql/blob/master/src/~/website/public/index.html#L12 if you're loading stuff relative then the nested urls could be pointing to the wrong folder

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am pretty sure that my path is correct. All the other plugins load just fine. They are in the same location. Only the jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js fails. It cannot find the require the tweenlite.js module although this file is also present. I verified it...I cannot find what this wrong with this specific library...

Comment: can you verify its still broken with the added base tag?

Comment: Unfortunately it is still broken...